# Alternative for Section and Parialview in Spring MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, spring-mvc

**--is their any alternative in spring MVC for *Partial views* as we use in ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor engine?**

**--is their any alternative in spring MVC for *Sections* as we use in ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor engine?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I develop in both: MVC.net and Spring MVC. I really like partial views in mvc.net but I don't think there is an out-of-the-box equivalent in Spring. However, I've done this with regular ajax calls using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$('#divContainer').load('pathToView/view #partialViewContent')
```

Alternatively, I've seen Spring examples where the view checks a model property that indicates whether the request is an Ajax call and if that's the case it will skip html, body, etc tags.

As far as sections, the closest thing I can think of is Apache Tiles:
http://tiles.apache.org/